# Retrofit returns unknown characters

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm having this weird error when using Retrofit.

First of all I tried using okhttpClient just for comparison and im getting the json result as expected.

```
  val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("email", "my.email@email.com")
        .build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(BASE_URL + "account/forgot")
        .post(requestBody)
        .build()
     var client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).execute()
        .use { response ->
            val response = response.body()!!.string()
    }
```

Which returns

```
    {"success": true, "email": "my.email@email.com", "uu_id": "000-0--0-0-000"}
```

Now Using the same logic, I tried converting it to retrofit but skip the GSON conversion as it returns unexpected error saying "JSON is not formatted"

so what I did was on callback, just return it as ResponseBody based on Retrofit's Documentation

```
@Headers("token: ", "accept-language: en-US", "accept: application/json", "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br", "Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("account/forgot")
fun resetPasswordDetails(@Body body:String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

And uses this RetrofitInstance

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(new ResponseInterceptor())
            .build();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(defaultHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

on my Main activity I used it as

```
    val service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService::class.java)

    val jsonBody = JSONObject()
    jsonBody.put("email", "my.email@email.com")

    val call = service.resetPasswordDetails(jsonBody.toString())
    val response = call.execute()
    val value = response.body()?.string()
```

I'm expecting the same result as what I did on okHttp but the return string was

```
      ���������������-�A
�0E�Rf)M1mc�+o"���)�ED�{��>��>PW"�.ݳ��w��Q����u�Ib�ȃd���x�/\r���@95s)�Eo���h�S����jbc���̚����  �������
```

Is there something wrong on my retrofit instance? Why is that it is working on okhttp but not on retrofit

EDIT:
My question is tagged as duplicate but I dont think thats the same question. While the other one states that the problem relates to URL encoding, My question is why is the okhttpclient and retrofit doesn't return the same JSON

Comment: @Arty I dont think thats the same question. While the other one states that the problem relates to URL encoding while my question is why is the okhttpclient and retrofit doesnt return the same JSON.

Comment: Do you have control of the server? It might be that the request is not being sent properly and the server responds with some kind of failure data encoded in the wrong way.

Comment: @JensV I dont have any control on web server. I tried using postman and it returns a valid json objects as well as okhttpclient. This unknown characters only shows when I used retrofit. I've tried adding charset UTF-8 on header but it still doesnt work

Comment: This doesn't look remotely similar to JSON. Some ideas: the server is replying using ProtoBuffers or some similar protocol; the response is gzip encoded but for some reason Retrofit or OkHttp is not able to decode it (maybe removing some of the headers you added could help, as this is usually handled automatically by Retrofit).

Comment: @Xavier Your comment is correct. I just need to delete some of my headers and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Xavier Rubio Jansana comment, I deleted some of my headers and now it is working properly. I just retain the  @Headers("Content-Type: application/json").. Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are sending the request as a JSON Body instead of Multipart like your OkHTTP request.

To make a Multipart request you can define your Retrofit request like this:

```
@POST("account/forgot")
fun resetPasswordDetails(@Part email:String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Then you can just call the method with the email address without creating any JSONObject.